# Email Service does not receive Apex Exception Mails in DE Org

Tags: email, managed-package, exception, apex-email-service

In an Managed Package, we want to produce an Custom Object for each Apex Exception Mail that we receive. In order to implement that we followed the instructions we found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49652/how-to-handle-error-emails-from-customer-orgs-as-an-isv-partner).

We created an Email Service which directs all mails to an Apex Class, which creates the Custom Objects.
[image]

The Email adress directing to the Email service is assigned to an User which is marked as "Notify on Apex Error" in the Package and has also "Send Apex Warning Mails" checked in his User profile.

In Package:

[image]

In User Profile:

[image]

If we manually send an Error Mail to the given adress the Code works just fine but if we provoke an Error, it seems as if there was no Apex Exception Mail sent. If we assign a normal adress to the user we only receive some error mails (1 out of 5). Has anyoone experiencied something similar or knows if DE Orgs handle Apex Exception Notification differently?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Since the post you  linked to has two answers and several other links, are you referring to the solution from Kevin Brommer's blog post on [My Pen Pal](http://kevinbromer.com/2011/03/apexapplication-my-pen-pal/)? `Send Apex Warning Emails` is normally for Salesforce system generated warning emails and isn't not related to external packages with custom objects that hold those things and wouldn't go through a custom email service, so I'm confused by that part of your question and not certain which errors you're referring to.

Comment: @Robert Mendez, were you able to implement this, I am trying to get the same code working by forwarding some exception emails but the matcher is not working.

Comment: We were able to implement this but our Regex is not able to capture all incoming Salesforce Error Mails. Some have a different structure so we need to improve on our Regex also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if there are multiple errors with the same root in a short period, Salesforce will just send one exception mail and wait for some time until it reacts on errors of the same kind again. I think this is to prevent Email accounts being overflooded with exception mails.

I dont know if this can be enabled but its definitely not an error of Salesforce.